# Getting 500 server error while updating page in elementor (when the custom widgets is added ) in woocommerce

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Created a custom widgets for elementor that can add upsells items to the cart all at once using ajax. For this i have leveraged wocoomerce upsells product features and for the discount i have created ACF fields to hold the coupons information and will be applied on checkout. All is working fine on frontend but when i hit update on elementor page builder the 500 error pops up but update do occur. Just worring if the following code have any security issues.

This i my custom widget php file:

```
<?php

/**
 * bundles item widgets
 * 
 * Elementor bundles  item widget to display in the single product page
 */
//  namespace WPC\Widgets;
//  use Elementor\Controls_Manager;
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
 class Elementor_Widget_3 extends \Elementor\Widget_Base
 {
  
    public function get_name() {
        return 'Bundle item'; 
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return esc_html__( 'Bundle item', 'custom-widget');
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'eicon-header';
    }

    public function get_custom_help_url() {}

    public function get_categories() {
        return ['basic'];
    }

    public function get_keywords() {}

    public function get_script_depends() {
        wp_register_script( 'widget-script-3', '/wp-content/themes/astra-child/custom-widgets/custom-widgets-assets/js/custom-bundle-item.js', __FILE__ );
        return
        [
            'widget-script-3'
        ];

    }

    public function get_style_depends() {
        wp_register_style( 'widget-style-3', '/wp-content/themes/astra-child/custom-widgets/custom-widgets-assets/css/custom-bundle-item.css', __FILE__ );
        return
        [
            'widget-style-3'
        ];

    }


    protected function register_controls() {
        $this -> start_controls_section(
            'section_content',
            [
                'label'=> 'settings',
            ]
        );
        $this -> add_control(
            'label_heading',
            [
                'label' => 'Label Heading',
                 'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                 'default' => 'Bundles items'
            ]
            );
          
            $this->end_controls_section();
    }

    protected function render() {
       
       global $product;
       $product_id = get_the_ID($product);
       $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
       $coupons_value = get_field('bundle_discount', $product_id);
       $product_coupons =  $coupons_value['value'];
       $product_coupon = $coupons_value['label'];
    

       $upsells = $product->get_upsell_ids();
    if(!empty($upsells)){
       ?>
       <div class="bundled-upsell">
       <p class="bundle-title"> Save More With Bundles</p>
       <div class="bundled-images">
       <?php
       $total = $product->get_price();//current product price.
       ?>
       <div class="custom-item-bundles">
       <?php
       echo $product->get_image();
       ?>
       <span>A$ <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></span>
       <label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="selected-item" data-product-quantity="1" data-product-id="<?php echo $product_id ?>" checked>
       This item: <strong><?php echo $product->get_title() ?></strong>
       </label>
       </div>
       <div class="plus-sign">+</div>
       <?php
        foreach($upsells as $upsell)
        {
           $up = wc_get_product($upsell);
           
           $price = $up->get_price();
           $image = $up->get_image();
           $title = $up->get_title();
           $item_link = $up->get_permalink();
           $total += $price;
           ?>
         <div class="custom-item-bundles">
         <a href="<?php echo $item_link ?>"><?php echo $image?></a>
         <span>A$ <?php echo $price ?></span>
         <label>   
         <input type="checkbox" class="selected-item" data-product-quantity="1" data-product-id="<?php echo $up->get_id()?>" checked>
         <a href="<?php echo $item_link ?>"><?php echo $title?></a>
         </label>
       
         </div>
       
           <?php
           if($upsell !== end($upsells))
           {
              ?><div class="plus-sign">+</div><?php
           }
       }   
       $final_total = round(($total - $total*($product_coupon/100)), 2);

    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="bundled-total">
        <div class="final-price">
           Was <span class="initial-price"> A$<?php echo $total?></span> 
           <strong>(<?php echo $product_coupon?>% OFF)</strong><br>
            <span> Bundled Offer: A$<?php echo $final_total ?></span>
        </div>
        <span> &#9889; Discount will be applied on checkout ! &#9889;</span>
        <button class="add-to-cart-bundled" id="add-to-cart-bundle">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bundled-item-ids" data-product-profile="<?php echo $product_coupons ?>"></div>
       </div>
       <?php
    }
 else
    {
       ;
    }
}
 

    protected function content_template() {}
}
```

This is my ajax file:

```
// Multi Ajax adda to cart
$ = jQuery;
function multiAddToCart( bundle ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/',
        type: 'POST', 
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            'action': 'multi_add_to_cart',
            'discount': coupons,
            'items' : Object.assign({}, bundle)
        },
        success : function(response) {
            $(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh'); // Refresh cart fragments
        },
        beforeSend: function (response) {
            $('#add-to-cart-bundle').html("Adding to cart");
        },
        complete: function (response) {
            $('#add-to-cart-bundle').html("Added to cart").prop('disabled', true).removeClass('add-to-cart-bundled').addClass('added-to-cart-bundled');
           
        },
        error : function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
var itemCoupons = $('.bundled-item-ids').data('product-profile');
var coupons = itemCoupons.toString();
$( '#add-to-cart-bundle' ).on('click', function() {
    bundle = [];
    $('.selected-item').each(function(){
                     if($(this).prop('checked')== true)
                     {
                         var cart_item = $(this).data('product-id');
                         var cart_quantity = $(this).data('product-quantity');
                         bundle.push({ product_id: cart_item, quantity: cart_quantity });
                     }
                 })

    multiAddToCart( bundle);
});
```

And this is my server side script

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_multi_add_to_cart', 'multi_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_multi_add_to_cart', 'multi_ajax_add_to_cart');


function multi_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    if (isset($_POST['items']) ) {
        $items = $_POST['items'];
        $discount = $_POST['discount'];
        
        if ( ! is_array( $items ) || empty( $items ) ) {
            wp_send_json_error( 'Invalid items list' );
        }
    
        // Add each item to the cart
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id   = absint( $item['product_id'] );
            $quantity     = absint( $item['quantity'] );
    
            // Validate the product ID
            if ( ! $product_id ) {
                continue;
            }
            
            // Add the item to the cart
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity);

        }
       
            $previous_coupons =  WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
            WC()->cart->remove_coupons($previous_coupons);

            // Apply the discount code
            $result = WC()->cart->apply_coupon($discount);
            if ( $result === true ) {
              // Discount applied successfully
              wc_add_notice( __( 'Discount code applied successfully.', 'woocommerce' ) );

            } 
           else {
            // Handle error message
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Invalid discount code.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
          }
        // Get the updated cart fragments
        $fragments = WC()->cart->get_cart_for_session();
    
        // Send the response
        wp_send_json_success( array(
            'fragments' => $fragments,
            'cart_hash' => WC()->cart->get_cart_hash(),
        ) );
    }
    die();
}
```

I did try increasing the memory limits,but no luck, also i have other custom widgets that are working fine.

And finally this is my error logs :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_upsell_ids() on bool in /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra-child/custom-widgets/custom-bundle-item.php:84\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(2268): Elementor_Widget_3->render()\n#1 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/widget-base.php(609): Elementor\\Controls_Stack->render_by_mode()\n#2 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/widget-base.php(673): Elementor\\Widget_Base->render_content()\n#3 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/db.php(202): Elementor\\Widget_Base->render_plain_content()\n#4 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/db.php(208): Elementor\\DB->render_element_plain_content(Array)\n#5 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/db.php(208): Elementor\\DB->render_element_plain_content(Array)\n#6 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/db.php(558): Elementor\\DB->render_element_plain_content(Array)\n#7 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/db.php(539): Elementor\\DB->get_plain_text_from_data(Array)\n#8 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/db.php(230): Elementor\\DB->get_plain_text(732)\n#9 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/base/document.php(1230): Elementor\\DB->save_plain_text(732)\n#10 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/base/document.php(742): Elementor\\Core\\Base\\Document->save_elements(Array)\n#11 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/documents-manager.php(510): Elementor\\Core\\Base\\Document->save(Array)\n#12 [internal function]: Elementor\\Core\\Documents_Manager->ajax_save(Array, Object(Elementor\\Core\\Common\\Modules\\Ajax\\Module))\n#13 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/common/modules/ajax/module.php(172): call_user_func(Array, Array, Object(Elementor\\Core\\Common\\Modules\\Ajax\\Module))\n#14 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): Elementor\\Core\\Common\\Modules\\Ajax\\Module->handle_ajax_request('')\n#15 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)\n#16 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#17 /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(188): do_action('wp_ajax_element...')\n#18 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra-child/custom-widgets/custom-bundle-item.php on line 84, referer: https://evpowerhouse523.e.wpstage.net/wp-admin/post.php?post=732&action=elementor
[Sat Jan 21 13:00:10.019386 2023] [php:warn] [pid 1383] [client 49.12.33.216:54300] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "id" on null in /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-product-attachment/admin/class-woocommerce-product-attachment-admin.php on line 462, referer: https://evpowerhouse523.e.wpstage.net/wp-admin/post.php?post=732&action=elementor
[Sat Jan 21 13:00:10.054040 2023] [php:warn] [pid 1383] [client 49.12.33.216:54300] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "id" on null in /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-product-attachment/admin/class-woocommerce-product-attachment-admin.php on line 462, referer: https://evpowerhouse523.e.wpstage.net/wp-admin/post.php?post=732&action=elementor
[Sat Jan 21 13:00:10.299971 2023] [php:warn] [pid 1383] [client 49.12.33.216:54300] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra-child/custom-widgets/custom-bundle-item.php on line 80, referer: https://evpowerhouse523.e.wpstage.net/wp-admin/post.php?post=732&action=elementor
[Sat Jan 21 13:00:10.299993 2023] [php:warn] [pid 1383] [client 49.12.33.216:54300] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/site/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra-child/custom-widgets/custom-bundle-item.php on line 81, referer: https://evpowerhouse523.e.wpstage.net/wp-admin/post.php?post=732&action=elementor`
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: its 500 internal server error

Comment: The reason for a 500 error is typically logged somewhere, check your php/apache logs.

Answer (score -1):

Try to enable error logging in wp-config and see exactly what the error is. You can enable this by changing:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );    
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Then check the error log file created in wp-content.

As you have suggested, it is likely memory limits with Elementor. I would set to 512M in php.ini.

Comment: Appreciated your answers, also I have edited the question again by including the php log errors.